# Light weight data store in Perl

Tags: perl

My requirement is to maintain a simple data store with some rows (~1000) & columns (6)

Over period of time (2 years) I am expecting the data to grow to 1000-1500 lines/rows

I would like query, insert & update in the data store

I need this data store because this needs to be processed by another script.

I am using Perl for programming.

I have seen some threads in Stackoverflow (ex: [looking for light-weight data persistence solution in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081818/looking-for-light-weight-data-persistence-solution-in-perl)) about this but I cannot make a decision

Anyone using light weight data store in Perl with query, insert & update capabilities ?

Comment: Can't make the decision for you, especially not with the criteria you gave - anything would fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already accepted the answer, but in your case, I might just go with hashes and use [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) to write my structure to a disk. That is, if you don't have multiple people using the data at once.

The advantage is that it's all standard Perl, so it will work with almost any Perl installation. Can't get any *lighter weight* than this.

Comment: Guess I will try this. Unable to install DBI for Rational Perl. :(

Answer (score 7):

Go for  `Sqlite.` It is powerful, tunable and lightweight.

Comment: do i need to install SQLite for this to be installed?

Comment: No, because the DBD-SQLite driver comes with its own copy of the C library.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest lightweight solution would be to use [DBI](https://metacpan.org/release/DBI) with [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/release/DBD-SQLite).

Answer (score 3):

If your data is relational and you are comfortable with SQL then I vote [DBD::SQLite](http://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aSQLite).

However if your data is more like documents (each entry data is self contained) or if you are not comfortable with SQL then I recommend [DBM::Deep](http://metacpan.org/module/DBM%3a%3aDeep). Its interface is exactly as easy to use as regular Perl variables.

Finally, if you want to be really modern, [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is very easy to install and the new [Mango](http://metacpan.org/module/Mango) Perl module is very cool, just saying :-)

Comment: is it possible to view the DBM::Deep db files?

Comment: They are binary somehow, I don't think that there is any way to view them except loading into Perl and dumping using Data::Dumper or the like